# hyperlink not being able to have image states, i.e onmousedown

Tags: asp.net

I have a quick question...I have a masterpage and is there anyway that I can target the contentarea without having to use hyper links? I have tried using buttons and link buttons but it never worked. The reason why is because I want to have button states and I'm not sure how to go about doing this. 
I have added an image to the link

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Tabbet.aspx"ImageUrl="~/Icons/Icon_english_a.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
```

and my code behind to try and show any state

```
void btn()
    {
        HyperLink1.Attributes.Add("onmousedown", "src='Images/logo.png'");
    }
```

when I click on the image, the image is not changing to a down state.

Thanks

Comment: you not need to do this thing using code behind,you can simply do using jquery

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jQuery, I've used it for sliders and spinners but nothing for something like this. Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes I have solution you should try following way:

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#<%=Hyperlink1.ClientID%> img").hover(function () {
                $(this).attr("src", "/Images/logo.png");
            }, function () {
                $(this).attr("src", "/Icons/Icon_english_a.png");
            }).mousedown(function () {
                $(this).attr("src", "/Images/logo.png");
            }).mouseup(function () {
                $(this).attr("src", "/Icons/Icon_english_a.png");
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. It works and now makes things more easier. Done it.

Comment: One more question, how do I apply this the other images? This works for one, I need it to work for up to 5...I should have asked that as well.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I just took out the (document).ready and left the $, and copy and pasted 5 of them and changed the hyperlink ids

Comment: heres the question..How to use jquery to change button states over multiple images