# How to use jquery to change button states over multiple images

Tags: jquery

I was wondering what is the proper way of using jquery to change HyperLinkImage States, i.e mousedown, onmouseup etc...other than copying and pasting the same function and changing id names?
Here is the code that I was just going to copy and paste and change the clientid parts to reflect 5 other image links

```
$(function () {

        $("#<%=HyperLink1.ClientID%> img").hover(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "/HoverIcons/Icon_lab.png");
        }, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "/ActiveIcons/Icon_lab_a.png");
        }).mousedown(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "/DownIcons/iconlab.png");
        }).mouseup(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "/ActiveIcons/Icon_lab_a.png");
        });
    });
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Here is the part where all the links are in my markup..

```
<div id="Navigation1">
            <div id="Nav">
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_lab_a.png" NavigateUrl="~/Tabbet.aspx">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_ABC_a.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_math_a.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_english_a.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_history_a.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_geography_a.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink7" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_cyberspace_a.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img alt="" class="auto-style3" src="ActiveIcons/New_subject_coming.png" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <img alt="" class="auto-style3" src="ActiveIcons/New_subject_coming.png" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

I'm just starting to change the code now, this is my layout for the images.

Comment: I edited my question and added the code that I was going to copy and paste and change the clientid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made this change in your .aspx file.

Add `CssClass="linkcssclass"` to your hyperlinks as follow:

```
<div id="Navigation1">
            <div id="Nav">
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" CssClass="linkcssclass" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_lab_a.png" NavigateUrl="~/Tabbet.aspx">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" CssClass="linkcssclass" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_ABC_a.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" CssClass="linkcssclass" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_math_a.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink4" CssClass="linkcssclass" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_english_a.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink5" CssClass="linkcssclass" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_history_a.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink6" CssClass="linkcssclass" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_geography_a.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink7" CssClass="linkcssclass" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_cyberspace_a.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <img alt="" class="auto-style3" src="ActiveIcons/New_subject_coming.png" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <img alt="" class="auto-style3" src="ActiveIcons/New_subject_coming.png" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                            &nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Make following changes in your jQuery:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".linkcssclass img").each(function (i) {
                $(this).hover(function () {
                       $(this).attr("src", "/HoverIcons/Icon_lab.png");
                }, function () {
                        $(this).attr("src", "/ActiveIcons/Icon_lab_a.png");
                }).mousedown(function () {
                   $(this).attr("src", "/DownIcons/iconlab.png");
                }).mouseup(function () {
                $(this).attr("src", "/ActiveIcons/Icon_lab_a.png");
              });
            });


        });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

i found this answer in other question:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#<%=Hyperlink1.ClientID%> img").hover(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "/Images/logo.png");
        }, function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "/Icons/Icon_english_a.png");
        }).mousedown(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "/Images/logo.png");
        }).mouseup(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", "/Icons/Icon_english_a.png");
        });
    });

</script>
```

Reference: [hyperlink not being able to have image states, i.e onmousedown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665340/hyperlink-not-being-able-to-have-image-states-i-e-onmousedown)

**UPDATE**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="nav">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" CssClass="lab" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_lab_a.png" NavigateUrl="~/Tabbet.aspx">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" CssClass="abc" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_ABC_a.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink3" CssClass="math" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/ActiveIcons/Icon_math_a.png">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
<table>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav a img').hover(function () {
      if($(this).parent().hasClass("lab"))
        $(this).attr("src", "/Images/lab_hover.png");
      //if hasClass("abc")
      //if hasClass("math")
  }, function () {
      if($(this).parent().hasClass("lab"))
            $(this).attr("src", "/Images/lab_a.png");
      //if hasClass("abc")
      //if hasClass("math")
  }).mousedown(function () {
    if($(this).parent().hasClass("lab"))
      $(this).attr("src", "/Images/lab_mousedown.png");
    //if hasClass("abc")
    //if hasClass("math")
  }).mouseup(function () {
    if($(this).parent().hasClass("lab"))
      $(this).attr("src", "/Images/lab_mouseup.png");
    //if hasClass("abc")
    //if hasClass("math")
  });
});
</script>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi, That was another of my questions that got answered. I didn't remember to ask everything that I needed to know in that, so I had to start a different question :)

Comment: you just need to add a class name to identify all your hyperlinks, then you have to replace the `$("#<%=Hyperlink1.ClientID%> img")` for `$('.your_hyperlink_class img')`

Comment: Forgive me for being a newb with jquery, but how would that work when all the states are different icons? one icon is an image of a lab that has its own images for states, and another link would be an image for history that has its own images for states.

Comment: in that case you will need to identify what images you need to use for every hyperlink. have you tried to use just simple CSS?
`div.hyperlink1_img { background-image: url(imge_url) }
div.hyperlink1_img:hover { background-image: url(hover_imge_url) }
div.hyperlink1_img:active { background-image: url(ative_imge_url) }` (for this you need a div inside your hyperlink)

Comment: Actually no, I never thought of that. That makes sense. Thanks for showing me another way of doing that.

Comment: Just looked it over, good job. Thanks for helping out as well I appreciate it.